# JpaRepository findBy boolean

Tags: spring-boot

I am implementing an API to return all flagged users (boolean true). I am novice on Spring Boot and I am wondering what would be the best way to implement that method on the `UserDAO`

Does that DAO method makes sense, I want to return a LIST a `Users` with `FLAG` set to true.

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "public")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "userid", nullable = false)
  private Long userId;

 @Column(name = "flag")
  private Boolean flag;
  public Boolean getFlag() {
    return flag;
  }

  public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
  }
```

**DAO**

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findByRoleId(Integer roleId);
```

**Service**

```
  public Execution<User> getFlaggedUsers() {
    Execution<User> res;
    try {
      List<User> users = userDao.findUsersByFlag();
      res = new Execution<>(ResultEnum.SUCCESS, users);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      res = new Execution<>(ResultEnum.INNER_ERROR);
    }
    return res;
  }
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/flagged_users")
public Map<String, Object> getFlaggedUsers() throws InternalException {
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        Execution<User> res = userService.getFlaggedUsers();
        resultMap.put(Constants.USER.getStatusCode(), res.getObjects());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InternalException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DAO method should be

`List<User> findByFlag(boolean flag)` where you can pass required flag.

Or

`List<User> findByFlagTrue()` which will returns all the users where flag = true.